# Is my answer a link only answer?

Tags: discussion, link-only-answers

I just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31162172/redmine-the-entry-or-revision-was-not-found-in-the-repository/31468736#31468736) with linking and explaing a tutorial I wrote by myself on the official redmine page. But I'm not sure if I have extracted enough from my tutorial into the answer of if I had to copy everything of it into the SO answer (because the redmine linke may get broken at any time).

If I compare my answer to like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957466/how-to-create-an-on-off-switch-with-javascript-css/1957501#1957501) I would say it's okay but as said I'm not quite sure and not yet very experienced in diving between "link only answer" and "non link only answer". So please give me some advise so I can scruntinze myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most important guideline is to think to yourself "if the link dies, is there enough useful information for the post to still be useful?". An easy way to test that would be to simply pretend that your post only had plaintext.

So, taking an example that Shog already [gave](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/189840) on the main Meta.SE site:

[image: i think you should take The tutorial HERE! This will help you a lot]

becomes

> i think you should take The tutorial HERE!
>
> This will help you a lot

where it's immediately clear that all of the useful information is in the link, making it a link-only answer.

---

Your answer post isn't quite that extreme, but I have to admit that if the link to the tutorial dies, I wouldn't be able to just use the plaintext in your post to solve the problem, so in that sense, it would still be a link-only answer.

Comment: That's a nice guideline with a practical example. Thank you! I'll update my answer in some minutes/hours (have work to do ^^). Thank you!